# Remove characters from a string C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have product codes in the following format:

1. 90004002
2. 90004034
3. 90012672

I need to remove the 90* characters until the first number that is not a zero, so the output should be:

1. 4002
2. 4034
3. 12672

So what I do is first remove the leading 9 and then the zeros, I want to know if there's a simpler way of doing this, a one liner?

```
string productCode = skuid.ToString().TrimStart('9');
productCode = productCode.TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: Is `9000009002` -> `2` or `9002`?

Comment: @Denis What is real type of skuid variable? Can't you cut it using regular loop? If it's something like byte[] array, it can be much faster that the string operations.

Comment: 9002, that's why I first remove the 9 and then the zeros

Comment: skuid is an int @rufanov

Comment: Could you have skuid like `91.....` or the first two chars are always a 9 followed by zero?

Comment: @Denis It's an int? `skuid - 9000000000` ?

Comment: @Denis, why then not just use something like "skuid-9000000000"? It's MUUUCH faster than converting to string, and stripping "first 9 and all nulls after"

Comment: @rufanov I suggest to post your comment as an answer. You are on the right track

Comment: @Denis, it's can't be int - all test values in this question is more than maximum value for int-datatype. is it "long" really, or it's a "uint"?

Comment: @rufanov sorry I've added too many zeros in my question.The numbers were purely for example. In the actual code they are int, I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

or try regex:

```
x = Regex.Replace(x, "^90*", "");
```

Comment: Thank you,this is nice and clean

Comment: @Denis: note that regex is less efficient than pure string methods. For such a simple and strict task i would prefer `TrimStart`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter regex solution is better than calling trimStart() twice considering immutability of string and regex is more cleaner and readable here.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: it's a matter of taste but i personally  find `TrimStart` much more readable than a regex. Apart form that even two `TrimStart` are 7 times faster than this regex. http://ideone.com/V1rNhq

Comment: All rather depends on the complexity of the problem doesn't it? This probably **is** slower than `TrimStart` but it is neater than chaining `TrimStart().Trimstart`, which you would need to do to satisfy @TimSchmelter 's own example of `9000009002`. Horses for courses though as the double `TrimStart` isn't exactly unreadable.

Comment: Gah! Didn't load new comments before writing and have basically just repeated what you said, Tim. Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

Why not....

```
string productCode = skuid.ToString().TrimStart('9', '0');
```

If  `9000009002`  is possible and should not be `2` but `9002`:

```
string productCode = skuid.ToString().TrimStart('9').TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: Er, that's not the same. What if `skuid.ToString()` evaluates to `9099`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: i have mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can write it like this:

```
string productCode = skuid.ToString().TrimStart('9').TrimStart('0');
```

But to be honest a regex would probably be cleaner here:

```
string productCode = Regex.Replace(skuid.ToString(), @"^90*", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions for that

```
string input = "9000004002";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^90*", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned in the comments that `skuid` is an `int`. You should treat it as such:

```
private const int PRODUCT_OFFSET = 90000000;

public void DoStuff() {
    int skuid = 90012672;
    int productCode = GetProductCode(skuid);
}

private int GetProductCode(skuId) {
    return skuId - PRODUCT_OFFSET;
}
```

Comment: Please update your OFFSET with the correct value edited by the poster

Answer (score 3):

> I need to remove the 90* characters until the first number that is not
>   a zero

How about ignoring first `9` in your string then parsing it to `int`? Like;

```
string s = "9000004002";
int i = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(1));
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()); //4002
```

I think this fits every case in your problem because parsing to `int` clears all leading zeros.